# rxjs combining BehaviorSubject and Zip Observables

Tags: d3.js, rxjs

I have the following js code.

```
var a = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(1);
var b = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(2);
var c = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(3);

var total = Rx.Observable.zip(a,b,c, d3.sum);

var observer1 = Rx.Observer.create(
    function (x) {
        console.log('this is an oberservation from A: ' + x);
    }
);

var observer2 = Rx.Observer.create(
    function (x) {
        console.log('this is an oberservation from TOTAL: ' + x);
    }
);

var subscription1 = a.subscribe(observer1)
var subscription2 = total.subscribe(observer2)

a.onNext(5)
```

The goal is that when `a` updates, `total` updates and that we can see the result printed in `observer2`. However the output when I run this is:

```
this is an oberservation from A: 1
this is an oberservation from TOTAL: 0
this is an oberservation from A: 5
```

Why don't I see a new total and why is the initial total wrong?

#### Edit

When I replace the `d3.sum` with `function(a,b,c){return a + b + c}` as the reducer function then at least the initial TOTAL score is correct. I don't know if this is a related issue but if it is I'd like to know what went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works when using

```
var total = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(a,b,c, function(a,b,c){return a + b + c})
```

The code before waits until `a`, `b` and `c` all have changed at least once before passing a message to the `observer2`.

Also, see [docs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/combinelatest.md).